# res.render load the same html page

Tags: node.js

My `index.js` file

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET new page. */
router.get('/new', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('new');

});
```

When the request is `http://localhost:3000/new` it still loads the index page. I want to be able to load the new html page.

Comment: Change the router sort and test again.

Comment: @Cr.did that....

Comment: I don't know what is the `router` defined and I guess it match the first and return, so the second router dose not work.